# How to take multiple arrays as input in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, io

I started learning C++ a week ago, coming from C.

The input I have is of the following format:

```
7
13 -4 -10 4 9 7 -3
4
0 -2 -1 2
2
3 5
0
```

The first number gives the number of elements in the first array. We stop scanning arrays once this number is a zero.

I would like to scan these arrays into an array of arrays as follows:

```
[[13,-4,-10,4,9,7,-3] , [0,-2,-1,2] , [3,5]]
```

I know how to scan in the first array:

```
int n;
int array1[MAXLENGTH];
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> array1[i];
    // scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
}
```

I get stuck on `0 -2 -1 2` since it starts with zero.

How can I scan in these arrays and stop once I encounter the last zero?

Comment: Why do you stop scanning at 0? If you stop scanning at 0, why do you ask for the number of elements? In any case, what is the desired behavior for the input `0 -2 -1 2`?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of array.  The `std::vector` can grow dynamically, using `push_back()`.

Comment: How do you know if it is the last 0 or an in-between 0?

Comment: It should be scanned in as another array, so in this case the program should scan in 3 arrays `[13,-4,-10,4,9,7,-3]`, `[0,-2,-1,2]` and `[3,5]`.

Comment: your code needs two distinct phases. Read the array length and if 0 stop. Then read the array (with no special 0 proccesing). Repeat

Comment: Are you reading all the data into one array or a 2d array?

Comment: The first read for each array is the number of elements `n`. It is only this number you need to check for zero, not the array elements.

Comment: Yes, I would like to scan the arrays into an array of arrays, i.e. `[[13,-4,-10,4,9,7,-3] , [0,-2,-1,2] , [3,5]]`.

Comment: @user6005857: No, you don't want to scan the data into an array of arrays.  You want to scan the data into a `vector` of `vector`.  The primary reason is the capacity of each array is not known at compile time.  To reduce the defects injected by dynamically allocating memory for the array, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes I need to get used to vectors. They aren't available in C unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input pattern is the same, regardless of data:

```
unsigned int array_index = 0U;
unsigned int quantity;
std::vector<std::vector<int> > database;
while (cin >> quantity)
{
  if (quantity == 0U)
  {
     break;
  }
  int value = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
  {
    cin >> value;
    database[array_index].push_back(value);
  }
  ++array_index;
}
```

A vector of vectors should be capable of containing the data.

The input data line:

```
4
0 -2 -1 2
```

The `4` represents the quantity of numbers for the second set.
The `0` is the first datum of the second set of data.

There are 3 sets of data in your input file.

Comment: The second `cin` should be checked for errors.  Don't trust the User or the data file.

Comment: You can probably fix this by a hack: add an empty array to the database: `database.push_back(std::vector<int>())` before the inner loop. The code currently uses out-of-range subscripts; this will make sure the subscript valid.

Comment: @anatolyg:  Good catch!  I forgot about the outer array and the push_back.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers, you should have two nested loops.

This is the outer loop:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;

while (true)
{
    int size = 0;

    std::cin >> size;
    if (size == 0)
        break;

    std::vector<int> array;
    ... // fill the array
    data.push_back(array);
}
```

C++ vectors have dynamic size. That is, you don't need to know what the size is when you define the dynamic array - it will adjust its size as elements are added into it (using `push_back`). This is convenient for the outer loop.

---

However, for inner loop, it's more convenient to use pre-allocated vectors, because your code "knows" the size of the array early:

```
std::vector<int> array(size); // allocate the array and set all elements to zero
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> array[i];
}
```

You can also use a range-based loop:

```
std::vector<int> array(size); // allocate the array and set all elements to zero
for (int& value: array)
{
    std::cin >> value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;
int array1[MAXLENGTH];
while(true)
{
cin >> n;
if(n == 0) break;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> array1[i];
    // scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
}
}
```

plus of course you should be using std::vector, and you are lossing your input since it is all stored in the same array getting overwritten each time.